# Check FLS for a record the user does not have sharing access to

Tags: lightning-aura-components, permissions, permission-sets, field-level-security, lightning-community

Is there any way to check FLS for a field on a record that the user does not have object (sharing) access to?

Object access is specifically not granted for this object because the user should not be able to freely view/edit the record using the standard pages and Lightning Communities do not have a way to disable these for objects other than revoking object access. Even though I am not using sharing, FLS is still a very powerful tool for admins to be able to control which aspects of a record a certain user can view/edit. The built in FLS access checks on `FieldDescribeResult` will all report false because these take object access into account.

Is there any mechanism where I can check the actual FLS settings for the user at the Profile and/or Permission Set level, then manually report these back to the component to control rendering?

Answer (score 2):

> If a user has permissions to specific fields you can list down using following SOQL, which returns based on user profile and permission sets that user is assigned to.

```
SELECT Id, Field, SObjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsEdit 
FROM FieldPermissions 
WHERE SObjectType = 'Account'
AND Parentid IN 
(SELECT permissionsetid 
    FROM PermissionSetAssignment 
    WHERE Assignee.Id = :Userinfo.getUserId())
```

> Results

[image: Field Permissions]

For more information, refer:

[User, Sharing, and Permission Objects](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_users.htm) data model

and [Using SOQL to Determine Your Force.com User’s Permissions](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html)

Comment: @dsharrison is that works for you?

Comment: For the most part yes, I am still working through some weird behavior I am getting with some setups. I'll accept this as the answer once I can get the remaining cases working.